# Trouble with Finding a Supremum Constrained by a Condition

Tags: mathematical-optimization, complex

I have a function

$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{\left(x^4 y+\frac{2 x^2 y^2}{x^2 y^2+1}+\frac{2}{x^2 y^2+1}-41 x^2 y-7 x^2\right)^2+\left(-7 x^3 y-x^3-\frac{2 x y}{x^2 y^2+1}-\frac{2 x^3 y^3}{x^2 y^2+1}+41 x\right)^2},
$$
in which I make the substitution: $x = x\cdot i$. Where $x\in[0,\propto), y \geq 0$. I aim to find the maximum value (supremum $y_{Max}$), for which $f(x\cdot i,y) > 0$ will be still positive.

The original function in Mathematica code is here:
`f[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(-7 x^2 - 41 x^2 y + x^4 y + 2/(1 + x^2 y^2) + (2 x^2 y^2)/(1 + x^2 y^2))^2 + (41 x - x^3 - 7 x^3 y - (2 x y)/(1 + x^2 y^2) - (2 x^3 y^3)/(1 + x^2 y^2))^2]`

Comment: What is non-described  $i$? Do you mean `(-7 x^2 - 41 x^2 y + x^4 y + 2/(1 + x^2 y^2) + (2 x^2 y^2)/(1 + x^2 y^2))^2 + (41 x - x^3 - 7 x^3 y - (2 x y)/(1 + x^2 y^2) - (2 x^3 y^3)/(1 + x^2 y^2))^2 >0`

Comment: i is the complex number

Answer (score 2):

`RegionPlot` gives an idea of the solution

```
RegionPlot[F[I x, y] > 0, {x, 1/1000 , 3}, {y, 0, 4} ,PlotPoints -> 50 ] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ulrich - I would like to ask if you used my function or some other. If I'm doing it right, the function doesn't have a numerical supremum, right?

Comment: @MartinStrmiska Indeed, there is no maximum `y`., just as Ulrich Neumann's plot suggests.  Use `Plot3D[f[I x, y], {x, 1/1000, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]`, if you prefer.